# Checking if a react block is ready for business

Tags: concurrency, thread-safety, raku, message-passing, rakudo

When writing concurrent code, it's fairly common to want to spin off a separate (green or OS) thread and then ask the code in that thread to react to various thread-safe messages.  Raku supports this pattern in a number of ways.

For example, many of the [Channel examples](https://docs.raku.org/language/concurrency#Channels) in the docs show code that's similar to the code below (which prints one through ten across two threads).

```raku
my $channel = Channel.new;
start   { react whenever $channel { say $_ }}
for ^10 { $channel.send($_) }
sleep 1
```

However, if we switch from the single-consumer world of `Channel`s to the multi-consumer world of live `Supply`s, the equivalent code no longer works.

```raku
my Supplier $supplier .= new;
start   { react whenever $supplier { say $_ }}
for ^10 { $supplier.emit($_) }
sleep 1;
```

This code prints nothing.  As I understand it, this is because the `react` block was not listening when the values were `emit`ed – it doesn't take long to `start` a thread and `react` to events, but it takes even less time to `emit` ten values.  And, logically enough, moving the `sleep 1` line above the `for` loop causes the values to print again.

And that's all fair enough – after all, the reason to use a live `Supply` rather than an on-demand one is because you want the live semantics.  That is, you want to only `react` to future events, not to past ones.

But my question is whether there's a way to ask a `react` block in a thread I've `start`ed whether it's ready and/or to wait for it to be ready before sending data.  (`await`ing the `start` block waits until the thread is *done*, rather than until it's ready, so that doesn't help here).

I'm also open to answers saying that I'm approaching this incorrectly/there's an X-Y problem – it's entirely possible that I'm straining against the direction the language is trying to push me or that live `Supply`s aren't the correct concurrency abstraction here.

Comment: I know there are upvotes for this but I just wanted to comment "great question".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For this specific case (which is a relatively common one), the answer would be to use a `Supplier::Preserving`:

```
my Supplier::Preserving $supplier .= new;
start   { react whenever $supplier { say $_ }}
for ^10 { $supplier.emit($_) }
sleep 1;
```

Which retains sent values until `$supplier` is first tapped, and then emits them.

An alternative, more general, solution is to use a `Promise`:

```
my Supplier $supplier .= new;

# A Promise used just for synchronization
my Promise $ready .= new;

start react {
    # Set up the subscriptions...
    whenever $supplier { say $_ }
    # ...and then signal that they are ready.
    $ready.keep;
}

# Wait for the subscriptions to be set up...
await $ready;

# ...and off we go.
for ^10 { $supplier.emit($_) }
sleep 1;
```

The `whenever`s in a `react` block set up subscriptions as they are encountered, so by the time the `Promise` is kept, all of the subscriptions will have been made. (Further, although not important here, no messages are processed until the body of the `react` block has finished setting everything up.)

Finally I'll note that while `Supplier` is often reached for, many times one would be better off writing a `supply` block that `emit`s the values. The example in the question is (quite reasonably enough) abstracted from a concrete application, but it's almost always worth asking, "can I do what I want by writing a `supply` block" before reaching for a `Supplier` or `Supplier::Preserving`. If you really do need to broadcast values or need to distribute asynchronous inputs to multiple places, there's a solid case for `Supplier`; if it's just a single stream of values to be produced once tapped, there probably isn't.