# Understanding Cro request/response cycle and memory use

Tags: raku, rakudo, cro

I'm a bit confused about how Cro handles client requests and, specifically, why some requests seem to cause Cro's memory usage to balloon.

A minimal example of this shows up in the [literal "Hello world!" Cro server](https://cro.services/docs/intro/getstarted#Write_a_Cro_service).

```raku
use Cro::HTTP::Router;
use Cro::HTTP::Server;

my $application = route {
    get -> {
        content 'text/html', 'Hello Cro!';
    }
}

my Cro::Service $service = Cro::HTTP::Server.new:
    :host<localhost>, :port<10000>, :$application;

$service.start;

react whenever signal(SIGINT) {
    $service.stop;
    exit;
}
```

All that this server does is respond to GET requests with "Hello Cro!' – which certainly shouldn't be taxing.  However, if I navigate to `localhost:10000` and then rapidly refresh the page, I notice Cro's memory use start to climb (and then to stay elevated).

This only seems to happen when the refreshes are *rapid*, which suggests that the issue might be related either to not properly closing connections or to a concurrency issue (a maybe-slightly-related [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69421730/understanding-the-point-of-supply-blocks-on-demand-supplies)).

Is there some performance technique or best practice that this "Hello world" server has omitted for simplicity?  Or am I missing something else about how Cro is designed to work?

Comment: By "stay elevated" do you mean that it doesn't give the RAM back to the operating system? Because that is what I would expect to happen with anything that has a garbage collector.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Cro request processing pipeline is a chain of `supply` blocks that requests and, later, responses pass through. Decisions about the optimal number of processing threads to create are left to the Raku `ThreadPoolScheduler` implementation.

So far as connection lifetime goes, it's up to the client - that is, the web browser - as to how eagerly connections are closed; if the browser uses a keep-alive HTTP/1.1 connection or retains a HTTP/2.0 connection, Cro respects that request.

Regarding memory use, growth up to a certain point isn't surprising; it's only a problem if it doesn't eventually level out. Causes include:

- The scheduler determining more threads are required to handle the load. Each OS thread comes with some overhead inside the VM, the majority of it being that the GC nursery is per thread to allow simple bump-the-pointer allocation.
- The MoarVM optimizer using memory for specialized bytecode and JIT-compiled machine code, which it produces in the background as the application runs, and is driven by certain bits of code having been executed enough times.
- The GC trying to converge on a full collection threshold.